# Executing Javascript inside of a PHP Redirect

Tags: javascript, php, bookmarklet, url-scheme

I've been experimenting with PHP forwarding to the end of making a modal window that appears with only a link and no modal script on the current page.

With PHP you can forward like this:

```
<?php
header( "Location: http://example.com" );
```

And also you can forward using alternate URL Schemes, for instance you can open an SMS Message like so:

```
<?php
header( "Location: sms:867-5309" );
```

So for instance you could have "http://yoursite.com/phone-number.php" start an sms conversation on a supporting device and also keep the page you left open.

I've also seen people use the URL Scheme "javascript:" to run javascript from the browser address bar or a bookmarklet.

---

**My Problem is:** Whenever I try to execute Javscript with the PHP header redirect nothing happens, like so:

```
<?php
header( "Location: javascript:alert('hey!');" );
```

**My Question is:** Why won't it execute and Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: [What is it you are trying to do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: `javascript:` urls are not a real URI scheme, they are just something your browser understands **in some cases where JavaScript is applicable**. Not so in a redirect. Also, other uri schemes like `sms` are often not coded into the browser specifically, but plugins that have more control.

Comment: `...HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path...` from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). The may share the `:` but certainly an `alert` is not a URI..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the `javascript` URI-scheme is just a fake [non-standardized](http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml) scheme, allowed by browsers for backwards compatibility in anchor elements to execute JS. It has been deprecated for a long time in favor of the correct event syntax, like this:

```
<a onclick="alert('hey!')">Click me!</a>
```

If you want to execute Javascript 'in a redirect' you should reverse the approach - instead of doing a server request directly, use an Ajax request to invoke the serverside code, and then use an `onSuccess` callback to execute the JS code to be run afterwards.

It is even possible, easily with libraries like jQuery or Mootools, or manually using [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), to have an Ajax request actually return Javascript code which is then executed, allowing you even more flexibility.

Comment: Regarding latest edit: you don't even need any library to *execute* the JS code you get back. Rather, just recommend `eval`. Saves time. **preemptive defense** Yes I know eval is evil but you probably trust the code coming from your own server.

Comment: Hence the 'easily' in between. It can of course be done manually with a custom XHR with `eval`, but for example in Mootools the [`evalScripts` flag defaults to `true`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request.HTML), and in jQuery it is also [default behaviour](http://api.jquery.com/load/#script-execution). I was just implying the libraries are there to solve issues like this in an easier way.

Comment: As I understand it, those links talk about code in `<script>` tags, and only if they are inserted into the doc, correct? Thus eval is easier to just run some plain code from the server

Comment: Correct, edited the answer to point towards the plain `eval` option.